# SDE: conditions for the process to be normal and/or stationary

Tags: normal-distribution, random, stochastic-differential-equations, stationary-processes

We have random process $X(t)$ satisfying the following SDE:
$dX(t)=A(X(t))dt+B(X(t))dW(t)$,
with $W(t)$ - Wiener process.

Does somebody know sufficient/necessary conditions on $A$ and $B$, that the random process $X(t)$ is normal and/or stationary?

I would be grateful for the literature, also in the complex case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend the following book on:

[Stochastic Stability of Differential Equations](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-642-23280-0)

Specifically Chapter 3 if I recall correctly.

Comment: Thanks, after 2,5 years I have no idea why I asked the question, but I will have a look in the book :).